# how to get index of duplicates in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sorted array like this:

```
var a= [
    {id:"1", name:"A", address:"A"},
    {id:"2", name:"A", address:"B"},
    {id:"3", name:"A", address:"C"},
    {id:"4", name:"B", address:"A"},
    {id:"5", name:"B", address:"B"},
    {id:"6", name:"C", address:"A"},
    {id:"7", name:"C", address:"B"},
    {id:"8", name:"C", address:"C"},..
```

What I want to do is get the index of those duplicated 'names' like

```
index 0-2 => "A";
index 3-4 => "B";
index 5-7 => "C";
```

Or even counting those duplicates will do such as `3` for A, `2` for B, `3` for C.

```
        var counter = 0;
        var prev = "";
        var next = "";
        var prevLink = a[0].name;

        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 

         if(i >= ssRow.length){
             //do nothing
        }else{        
          next  = a[i+1].name;  
        } 

        if(prev== next){
          counter++;
        }else{        
          counter = 0;
          prevLink = a[i].name;      
        }
          //play with counter variable
        }
```

But it's not working as expected. Is there a much better way or efficient way to do it?

Comment: @silentcoder14,it is working for you ?

Comment: did you checked my answer ? I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 let dupes = {};
 const array= [
        {id:"1", name:"A", address:"A"},
        {id:"2", name:"A", address:"B"},
        {id:"3", name:"A", address:"C"},
        {id:"4", name:"B", address:"A"},
        {id:"5", name:"B", address:"B"},
        {id:"6", name:"C", address:"A"},
        {id:"7", name:"C", address:"B"},
        {id:"8", name:"C", address:"C"}];
 array.forEach((item,index) => {
   dupes[item.name] = dupes[item.name] || [];
   dupes[item.name].push(index);
 });       
 for(let name in dupes) console.log(name+'->indexes->'+dupes[name]+'->count->'+dupes[name].length)
```

Comment: array.forEach((item,index) => {
   dupes[item.name] = dupes[item.name] || [];
   dupes[item.name].push(index);
 });  

can this be done in a normal for loop?

Comment: @silent_coder14, yes, you should use a `for` statement

Comment: thanx.. also, what this line means:

dupes[item.name] = dupes[item.name] || [];

Comment: This line mean following: if `dupes[item.name]` is undefined then initialize it with new array, and if not remains same.

Comment: @silent_coder14 yes a normal for loop can be used with the same block of code even for the conventional for loop. either `for(let index in array){const item = array[index]; //rest same code block from original answer }` or `for(let index=0; index<array.length; index++){const item=array[index]; //rest same code block from original answer}` can be used!

Comment: @silent_coder14 please accept the answer if you found this useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` to return object as result with both count and start-end index for each name.

```js
var arr = [{"id":"1","name":"A","address":"A"},{"id":"2","name":"A","address":"B"},{"id":"3","name":"A","address":"C"},{"id":"4","name":"B","address":"A"},{"id":"5","name":"B","address":"B"},{"id":"6","name":"C","address":"A"},{"id":"7","name":"C","address":"B"},{"id":"8","name":"C","address":"C"}]

var l = null;

var result = arr.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if (!r[e.name]) {
    l = e.name;
    r[e.name] = {
      count: 1,
      index: i.toString()
    }
  } else {
    if (arr[i + 1] && arr[i + 1].name != l || !arr[i + 1]) r[e.name].index += '-' + i;
    r[e.name].count++
  }
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ES6` [**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from?v=control) method.

**Try this it will work as per your expectation :**

```js
var a = [
    {id:"1", name:"A", address:"A"},
    {id:"2", name:"A", address:"B"},
    {id:"3", name:"A", address:"C"},
    {id:"4", name:"B", address:"A"},
    {id:"5", name:"B", address:"B"},
    {id:"6", name:"C", address:"A"},
    {id:"7", name:"C", address:"B"},
    {id:"8", name:"C", address:"C"}];

// fetch all the name property value into an array.
var nameArr = Array.from(a, x => x.name);

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < nameArr.length; i++) {
    var elem = nameArr[i];

    // if we haven't seen the element yet, 
    // we have to create a new entry in the map
    if (!obj[elem]) {
        obj[elem] = [i];
    }
    else {
        if(obj[elem].indexOf(nameArr.lastIndexOf(elem)) == -1) {
          // otherwise append to the existing array
          obj[elem].push(nameArr.lastIndexOf(elem));
        }
    }
}
 
for (var i in obj) {
  console.log('index ' +obj[i].join('-')+ ' => "'+i+'"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do more simply using `filter` method in combination with `forEach`.

The first step is to find out the `unique` names from your `array`. This can be achieved using `Set` method from `ES6`.

```
var names=[...new Set(array.map(a=>a.name))];
```

or

**UPDATE**

```
 names=array.map(a=>a.name).filter(function (x, i, a) { 
      return a.indexOf(x) == i; 
 });
```

Then you should use `filter` method, which accepts a `callback` provided function , in order to get the items which have `name` equals to one element from `names` array.

```js
var array= [
    {id:"1", name:"A", address:"A"},
    {id:"2", name:"A", address:"B"},
    {id:"3", name:"A", address:"C"},
    {id:"4", name:"B", address:"A"},
    {id:"5", name:"B", address:"B"},
    {id:"6", name:"C", address:"A"},
    {id:"7", name:"C", address:"B"},
    {id:"8", name:"C", address:"C"}];
    
var names=[...new Set(array.map(a=>a.name))];
names.forEach(function(item){
  indexes=array.map(function(item,i){
     item["index"]=i;
     return item;
  })
  .filter(a=>a.name==item)
  .map(a=>a.index);
  console.log(indexes[0]+'-'+indexes[indexes.length-1]+'->'+item+', count= '+indexes.length);
});
```

Comment: nope, I can't use ... new Set. It gives me syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

For counting the duplicates, you can use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which has a method called `_.groupBy()`[(see this)](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy). It gives you an object of key-value pairs where keys are the value you want to check for duplication and value is the array of objects what have that key. Its like this -

```
  var groupedData = _.groupBy(array, function(elem){
       return elem.name; //here you can specify whichever key you want to check duplicates for
  });

  console.log(groupedData['A'].length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and check the predecessor if the name is not the same or at the first index, then create a new array with the index information.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", name: "A", address: "A" }, { id: "2", name: "A", address: "B" }, { id: "3", name: "A", address: "C" }, { id: "4", name: "B", address: "A" }, { id: "5", name: "B", address: "B" }, { id: "6", name: "C", address: "A" }, { id: "7", name: "C", address: "B" }, { id: "8", name: "C", address: "C" }],
    groups = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        (!i || aa[i - 1].name !== a.name) && r.push([i, i, a.name]);
        r[r.length - 1][1] = i;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `groupBy` method in underscore. It doesn't do the full job of formatting it, but gets you to a good place to carry on with it.

```js
var data = [{ id: "1", name: "A", address: "A" }, { id: "2", name: "A", address: "B" }, { id: "3", name: "A", address: "C" }, { id: "4", name: "B", address: "A" }, { id: "5", name: "B", address: "B" }, { id: "6", name: "C", address: "A" }, { id: "7", name: "C", address: "B" }, { id: "8", name: "C", address: "C" }],

groups = _.groupBy(data, 'name');
console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't use external libs.

Comment: @silent_coder14 that's a shame, the above is very handy and readable. I hope it's useful for future reader's with the same problem but not the same restrictions